# Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string - First selecting, then adding a result combined with a form object

Tags: php, html

I want to insert data into SQL using PHP, but everytime I try it gets me an error. I use PDO to enter it, but it cant convert to string. Why is it saying this? 
The error lays in line 25, which is $partij->bindParam(':partij', $partij);
Code is below:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');


if (! $_SESSION['logged']) {
    header('location: login.php');
}
$member = $_POST['memberinp'];
$partij = $_POST['partyinp'];

$stack = $dbh->prepare("SELECT partij, stack FROM tbl_partijoverzicht WHERE partij = :partij");
$stack->bindParam(':partij', $partij);
$stack->execute();

$resultstack = $stack->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($member);
var_dump($partij);
var_dump($resultstack);

$partij = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_partijen(fullname,partij,stack) VALUES (:fullname,:partij,:stack)');

$partij->bindParam(':fullname', $member);
$partij->bindParam(':partij', $partij);
$partij->bindParam(':stack', $stack);

$partij->execute();

//header("location: admin.php");
$_SESSION['addedafmelding'] = true;
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `$stack` is a PDOStatement. You cannot pass it to bindParam.

Comment: `$dbh->prepare` will return PDOStatement object. You are tryong to bind it to a placeholder here `$partij->bindParam(':stack', $stack);`. What do you want to insert actually? And do closeCursor after a select query

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a `insert into ... select` query?

Answer (score 0):

You want the `'stack'` element of `$resultstack`

```
$partij->bindParam(':stack', $resultstack['stack']);
```

Comment: The error lays in line 25, which is `$partij->bindParam(':partij', $partij);`

Comment: You are using `$partij` twice. Once from your `$_POST` and the once as the result of your `prepare()`. You need to use a different variable for your `prepare()`.

Comment: It fails using your code, error is now in 28 ($partij->execute) because it says Column 'stack' can't be null

Comment: Then you are not getting the data you want out of the table. What is in `$resultstack`?

Comment: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["partij"]=>
    string(7) "SaxAlt1"
    ["stack"]=>
    string(48) "https://kmostack.damienvg99.nl/s/youmaynotknowthiskey"
  }
}`